# Remove span tag from attribute title text using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove `<span>` and `<i>` tag along with text in the title attribute.
I have tried `replace(/<span>(.*?)<\/span>/g, '')` but it's not working. Anyone help to achieve this.

```js
containerval =  $('p').attr('title')
k = containerval.replace(/<span>(.*?)<\/span>/g, '')
console.log(k,'kkkk')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p title="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy <span class='required'>*</span><i class='fa fa-info-circle attr_info cont_row_info' title='Enter Hrs'></i>">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry</p>
```

Comment: try `/<(span|i)[^>]*>.*?<\/\1>/g`

Comment: Why do you even have HTML in the title? Also safer to create an html fragment and remove

Answer (score -1):

Replace everything that is between `<` and `>`:

```js
const containerval =  $('p').attr('title')
const title = containerval.replace(/<.*>/, '').trim()
console.log({ title })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p title="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy <span class='required'>*</span><i class='fa fa-info-circle attr_info cont_row_info' title='Enter Hrs'></i>">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

Do not use regex to parse HTML

Instead you can use a fragment if you trust the content

```js
let $div = $("<div/>").html($('p').attr('title'))
console.log($div.html())
$div.find("span,i").remove()
console.log($div.html())
$('p').attr("title",$div.text())
console.log($('p').attr("title"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p title="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy <span class='required'>*</span><i class='fa fa-info-circle attr_info cont_row_info' title='Enter Hrs'></i>">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

Reusable and best approach.

```js
const tagRemover = (string, htmlTag) => {
  const RX = `<${htmlTag}.*?>.*?<\/${htmlTag}>` 
  return string.replace( new RegExp( RX, 'ig'),'')  
}

const p = document.querySelector('p')
const myString = p.getAttribute('title')

console.log('Removed <span> tag  ', tagRemover(myString, 'span'));
console.log('Removed <i> tag  ', tagRemover(myString, 'i'));


const spanTagRemoved = tagRemover(myString, 'span')
const iTagRemovedToo = tagRemover(spanTagRemoved, 'i') 
p.setAttribute('title', iTagRemovedToo)
```

```html
<p title="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy <span class='required'>*</span><i class='fa fa-info-circle attr_info cont_row_info' title='Enter Hrs'></i>">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry</p>
```